# OrnementsADF and babelbib font problem

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, packages, babel, font-encodings

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adforn}
\pdfmapfile{+OrnementsADF.map}

\begin{document}
\part{Part}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

When the package `babelbib` is included, it throws the following warnings:
[image: problem]

Without `babelbib`, no warning is thrown.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: There is *no* problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As egreg says, the warnings do not indicate any problem. They are simply telling you that the font is not available in a particular encoding, and that LaTeX has therefore substituted a fall-back. This is fine because the font isn't expected to be available in that encoding and it is substituting something appropriate.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[french]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage{adforn}

\begin{document}
ABC
\end{document}
```

Note that you do NOT need to add the map file manually unless you have installed the package manually and failed to update the map files correctly. That is, if you need to add the map file manually, something is wrong with your installation. (Probably relatively trivial to fix, but it is something wrong nonetheless.)

Exception: if you are using all the package files in the same directory as your `.tex` document, adding the map file within your document is probably the way to go. But I can't imagine why you'd want to do that and I'm pretty sure that you would need to add the map before loading the package, in that case.

Curiously, the warnings are only generated on the second and subsequent compilation runs. Removing the `.aux` file removes the warnings for the following compilation. There is no reason to do this as the warnings don't indicate anything is wrong, but I was just being curious.

In fact, the example can be made even more minimal. The following is sufficient:

```
\documentclass[french]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\newcommand{\Pifont}[1]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontencoding{U}%
\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\Pifont{OrnementsADF}

\begin{document}
ABC
\end{document}
```

Indeed, the following is sufficient:

```
\documentclass[french]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\newcommand{\Pifont}[1]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontencoding{U}%
\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\Pifont{pzd}

\begin{document}
ABC
\end{document}
```

So the non-problem is a result of `adforn`'s calling `\Pifont` prior to `\begin{document}`.

Although the warnings are not a problem, I'm not sure whether this is something I ought not be doing i.e. I'm not sure if it might actually cause a problem under some conditions.

I'm also not sure why this only seems to be a problem with certain languages. It is not a `babelbib` problem *per se*. If I use `british` rather than `french`, I don't get the warnings.

Because `\Pifont{}` has been called earlier, the active font at the beginning of the document is the ornament font, I think. But I am not entirely sure what code executed at the beginning of the document by `babelbib` is doing. For example, it seems to be executing something like `\AtBeginDocument{... \AtBeginDocument{...}...}` and I have no idea what purpose the nesting serves. There is also code it executes for `french` but not other languages at the beginning of the document. But it does all of this on the first run as well as the second, so I'd expect consistent warnings in that case.

I'm afraid this includes more questions than answers. If egreg were not so certain, I'd be tempted to say that `adforn` ought not be calling `\Pifont{}` before `\begin{document}`. Not because the warnings you are seeing are a problem but because I'm worried that doing that is affecting the encoding used for typesetting numerals, and may have other untoward side-effects. (LaTeX is looking for OT1 rather than T1. Changing the package loading order changes the encoding it is looking for in ways I don't like. Though I'm not sure that `adforn` is responsible for its infidelity.)

But since egreg is so certain, my worries are surely unfounded...?

Comment: I blame French. `;-)`